# Cannot properly display a manually created graph with Gephi Toolkit 0.9.1

Tags: java, toolkit, gephi

I am trying to use the Gephi Toolkit 0.9.1 to manually create and display a graph, but I can't seem to get the correct output. I've seen plenty of code which imports a file and creates a graph from that, but that method uses containers, which don't seem to make sense if you have nothing to import. Below is my code (most of which is just pieces of the demo code smashed together). Below that is a link to the display I am getting, which is just a solid colored rectangle. It seems to just be an edge (albeit, weirdly formatted), because when I changed the edge color, the display changed accordingly. I have tried it with 2 nodes and 1 edge, as well as 3 nodes and 2 edges. Both have the exact same output, as far as I can tell. I am incredibly new to using the Gephi Toolkit, so I'm sure the mistake is reasonably simple and I appreciate any help you can give. Thank you!

Jason

```
public class BasicGraphBuild {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicGraphBuild bscGraphBuild = new BasicGraphBuild();
    bscGraphBuild.script();
}

public void script() {
    ProjectController pc =
            Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
    pc.newProject();
    Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

    GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault()
            .lookup(GraphController.class).getGraphModel();

    Node n0 = graphModel.factory().newNode("n0");
    n0.setLabel("Node 0");
    Node n1 = graphModel.factory().newNode("n1");
    n1.setLabel("Node 1");
    Node n2 = graphModel.factory().newNode("n2");
    n2.setLabel("Node 2");

    Edge e1 = graphModel.factory().newEdge(n0, n1, 0, 1.0, true);
    Edge e2 = graphModel.factory().newEdge(n0, n2, 0, 1.0, true);

    DirectedGraph directedGraph = graphModel.getDirectedGraph();
    directedGraph.addNode(n0);
    directedGraph.addNode(n1);
    directedGraph.addNode(n2);
    directedGraph.addEdge(e1);
    directedGraph.addEdge(e2);

    // Preview configuration
    PreviewController previewController =
            Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PreviewController.class);
    PreviewModel previewModel = previewController.getModel();
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_CURVED,
            Boolean.FALSE);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.DIRECTED,
            Boolean.TRUE);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_COLOR,
            new EdgeColor(Color.CYAN));
    // previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_OPACITY,
    // 50);
    // previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_RADIUS,
    // 10f);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            Color.WHITE);

    // New Processing target, get the PApplet
    G2DTarget target = (G2DTarget) previewController
            .getRenderTarget(RenderTarget.G2D_TARGET);
    PreviewSketch previewSketch = new PreviewSketch(target);
    previewController.refreshPreview();
    previewSketch.resetZoom();

    // Add the applet to a JFrame and display
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Preview");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(previewSketch, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(1024, 768);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

[>>Output of the code<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh3Y9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this, thanks to the Gephi forums. I needed to set the x and y coordinates of the nodes so that they weren't stacked on top of each other. This was done by using the node.setX and node.setY methods.